# Tkinter-how to 'get' data values from more than one entry box using one button?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Just looking for some advice on a little GUI I'm practising with.
I'm trying to make a GUI for bending moments with a view to expand at some point...What I'm looking for is a method to grab the data from all the entry boxes using one button. I can get something working by having an individual button per entry box but I'd much rather have a simple 'submit' button...
Any help or advice is much appreciated,
cheers

current code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class beam(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()

        self.ent1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent1.grid(row=10,column=2)
        self.ent2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent2.grid(row=12,column=2)
        self.ent3 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent3.grid(row=14,column=2)
        self.ent4 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent4.grid(row=16,column=2)
        self.ent5 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ent5.grid(row=18,column=2)

        cls_btn = tk.Button(self,text='close', command=self.cls_win)
        cls_btn.grid(row = 30, column = 2)

        lbE = tk.Label(self,text='Youngs Modulus')
        lbE.grid(row=10,column=1)
        lbD = tk.Label(self,text='Outer diameter')
        lbD.grid(row=12,column=1)
        lbd = tk.Label(self,text='Inner diameter')
        lbd.grid(row=14,column=1)
        lbL = tk.Label(self,text='Length')
        lbL.grid(row=16,column=1)
        lbw = tk.Label(self,text='UDL')
        lbw.grid(row=18,column=1)

    def btns(self):
        self.ent1 = float(self.ent1.get())
        self.ent2 = float(self.ent2.get())
        self.ent3 = float(self.ent3.get())
        self.ent4 = float(self.ent4.get())
        self.ent5 = float(self.ent5.get())

    def cls_win(self):
        self.destroy()

def main():

    app = beam(None)
    w, h = app.winfo_screenwidth(), app.winfo_screenheight()
    app.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    app.title('Beam app')
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can get each entry box to submit using:

```
self.btn1 = tk.Button(parent, text='Submit', command=self.btns)
```

Comment: ebarr - thanks for the edit! I was sure I'd done it correctly this time....

Comment: You already have a function that gets all the values with a single button (`btns`). You overwrite the widget references, but your code does in fact get all the values with a single button click.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Indeed I do! I managed to confuse myself and hadn't realised how to use it...cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a clear problem in the code in the following function:

```
def btns(self):
    self.ent1 = float(self.ent1.get())
    self.ent2 = float(self.ent2.get())
    self.ent3 = float(self.ent3.get())
    self.ent4 = float(self.ent4.get())
    self.ent5 = float(self.ent5.get())
```

Here you are overwriting the `self.ent?` attributes, meaning that you can only execute `btns` once. Executing it twice will give an `AttributeError`, specifically:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
```

To answer your question, you are already getting the all of the entry boxes values with one button, so it is hard to tell what the problem is. However a minimal example of what you describe would be:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.pack()

# This function is executed by the submit button
# it retrieves the outputs of both entry boxes
def submit():
    print e1.get()
    print e2.get()

tk.Button(root,text="submit",command=submit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The code above does work as written, I can also retrieve the text using individual buttons for each entry box. What I'm looking for is a way to retrieve the input using just one button rather than five (currently). Apologies if this was unclear and thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create Entry box first and grid it at last will work.
For example

```
import tkinter,tkinter.messagebox,tkinter.simpledialog as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
large_font=("Verdana",12)
class way(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        a=tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container=tk.Frame(a)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.menu = tk.Menu(a, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Beep", command=self.bell)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Exit")
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.showMenu)
        self.frames={}
        for f in (pa1,pa2,pa3,pa4,pa5,pa6,pa7,pa8,pa9,pa10):
            frame=f(container,self)
            self.frames[f]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(pa1)
        menu=tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        file=tk.Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit',command=self.over)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=file)
    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
    def over(self):
        self.destroy()
    def sample(self,ev):
        print(ev)
    def showMenu(self, e):
        self.menu.post(e.x_root, e.y_root)
class pa1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
        a=ttk.Button(self,text='Dealer',command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa2)).grid(row=0,column=0)
        b=ttk.Button(self,text='Branch',command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa3)).grid(row=1,column=0)
        c=ttk.Button(self,text='Customer',command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa4)).grid(row=2,column=0)
        #I like to use bind but it does not support please tell me the reason why it does not support it.
class pa2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
        l1=tkinter.ttk.Label(self,text='Enter dealer id :',width=20)
        l2=tkinter.ttk.Label(self,text='Enter dealer password :',width=20)
        e1=tkinter.ttk.Entry(self)
        e2=tkinter.ttk.Entry(self)
        print(type(e1),type(e2),type(tkinter.ttk.Entry()))
        b1=ttk.Button(self,text="Back",command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa1)).grid(row=2,column=0)
        b2=ttk.Button(self,text='Submit',command=lambda:self.check(e1,e2)).grid(row=2,column=1)
        l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        l2.grid(row=1,column=0)
        e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    def check(self,e1,e2):
        try:
            a=e1.get()
            b=e2.get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            print('No error')
class pa3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
        b=ttk.Button(self,text="back",command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa1)).grid(row=0,column=0)
class pa4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
        b=ttk.Button(self,text="back",command=lambda:con.show_frame(pa1)).grid(row=0,column=0)
class pa5(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
class pa6(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
class pa7(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
class pa8(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
class pa9(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
class pa10(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,con):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent);
a=way()
a.mainloop()
```